# BASH can't find file which does exist

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a backup from a database, but in case the database file is below a certain size, I don't want it to overwrite over the last.sql which is the file imported whenever I boot up the project.

Here is my export script

```
cd /app/builds/databasefiles/

echo -e "currently in directory $(pwd)"
    # copy the new one to its own file with datetime information
filename_with_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").sql

_print "filename: " ${filename_with_date}

# Export database to location
docker-compose exec db mysqldump -ularavel -p"laravel" laravel > /app/builds/databasefiles/${filename_with_date}

_print "Wait for the database export to be complete"
sleep 5

minimumsize=200

actualsize=$(du -k "${filename_with_date}" | cut -f 1)

if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
    cp /app/builds/databasefiles/${filename_with_date} /app/builds/databasefiles/last.sql
else
    RED='\033[0;31m'
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
    printf "${RED}Could not backup your database.\n${NC}"
fi
```

The problem is however that I keep receiving the following response:

```
filename:  2017-03-03_10:49:29.sql
Wait for the database export to be complete
du: cannot access '2017-03-03_10:49:29.sql': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/vc: line 40: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

And when I check the files inside the database folder, I do see the 2017-03-03_10:49:29.sql file. I was wondering why the script is saying it can't find the file, and what I'd need to change to make sure this does work?

Comment: You seem to be putting the file you create here : campusinc_db/${filename_with_date} but you're not looking in the same place for it with the du command.

Comment: That's because the file is in `/app/builds/databasefiles/` folder. Try `actualsize=$(du -k "/app/builds/databasefiles/${filename_with_date}" | cut -f 1)` instead.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it's in the same directory that I can guarantee, I tried editing the file locations for this

Comment: I have updated the path, but in my project all paths are the same.

Comment: @killstreet That doesn't change anything. `2017-03-03_10:49:29.sql` and `/app/builds/databasefiles/2017-03-03_10:49:29.sql` are not the same file unless your script's working directory is `/app/builds/databasefiles/`.

Comment: The problem is that your `du` command that you pipe to `cut` can't find the file, because the file is in those nested folders. You have to tell `du` where your file is located.

Comment: @JNevill this worked, it seemed that setting the path earlier in the script didn't work and it needed to be a full path for DU

Comment: Yep. You could set the working path for the entire script by doing `cd /app/builds/databasefiles/` before doing anything else. But... that's sort of ugly. You could also change the ${filename_with_date} variable to concat the path to the front of it like `filename_with_date="/app/builds/databasefiles/${filename_with_date}"` and then you can omit the path.

Comment: Well earlier in the script I did do cd /app/builds/databasefiles/ to set the current directory, but somehow it doesn't sticks later on. But it's fine. Setting the full-path inside the DU command worked just fine!

Comment: I'll be darned, you sure do. I just don't know then. When in doubt, hard code your path, I suppose. If you do that `cd` outside of this script, and then call the script, then that may cause the behavior you are seeing. subshells can be snotty like that.

Comment: I would just add that having colons in the file name is not a great idea as they will always need to be escaped of fully quoted.  Issue is location of file to du command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the size of the file created by the `docker` command, you have to pass the correct name to `du`.

```
actualsize=$(du -k "/app/builds/databasefiles/${filename_with_date}" | cut -f 1)
```

Comment: Yes this worked, Though I tried setting the directory earlier in my script and thought it would work, but looks like it needs to be a full-path inside the du command non the less.

Comment: You never set a path; you just specified an absolute path for the `docker` command to write to. Unless you change the value of `filename_with_date`, you need a full path as the argument to `du` for the same reason you need a full path as the argument to `cp`.

Comment: This isn't the entire script, this function is called by another function which does do a cd /app/builds/databasefiles/

Comment: And that's why questions require a *complete*, verifiable example. The code you showed us, which is all we have to work with, does *not* have a `cd`.

Comment: I've updated the script I had, this is how it's set now, that does not work for me. I have to put the full path for the DU command.